# MS Access email when a linked table has been updated

Tags: ms-access

I’m new to MS Access so any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have searched this website and others for a solution but can’t seem to find a simple one.  Apologies if this has already been asked.

All I need is an email sent to me from Access when a linked table has been updated.  The email should contain details of the new record that has been inserted into the table. In the example below the ID 2 has been inserted into the linked table so the email should contain the details for ID 2.

**ID Desc**

1 *Desc1*

2 *Desc2*

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: 1. How are users updating your table? Only through a form, or also directly in the table (or a query)? 2. Which Access version do you use?

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply.  The table is updated infrequently e.g. every couple of weeks or even months with a direct entry - no forms.  And the table is opened in 2010 and 2003.

Answer (score 0):

In Access 2010 you can use a [Data Macro](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-data-macro-b1b94bca-4f17-47ad-a66d-f296ef834200) for the AfterInsert event. It even has a "Send Email" action, but I don't think you can use data from the inserted record in the email.

You can call a VBA function with some sort of hack, by using the `SetLocalVar` action, see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3db4c240-3d0b-4ddd-b926-dd5bcad36c6b/run-vba-code-from-within-2010-data-macro).

> I was able to use SetLocalVar and in the Expression enter the name of a Public Function in a standard module.

In Access 2003 this feature does not exist. If users insert directly in the table, you're out of luck (well, you can have an Access instance running 24/7 and in a Timer loop check for changes).

If you use a form, you can use the `AfterInsert` event to send the email.

Comment: Thanks again.  I'll look into using the AfterInsert event.